# Generating multiple calendars in iframe

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I have a google apps for education account and an app script run inside a gadget, which gets all of the calendars that a user belongs to/ owns. I am then generating urls based on their role. It seems that admin users can see all of their calendars but normal users need to specifically click on "Subscribe to calendar" or visit https://www.google.com/calendar/render#main_7 then reload the gadget to be able to view their calendars.

```
 if (role == "student") {
    url = "https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?        
    showTitle=0&showTabs=1&showCalendars=1&height=600&wkst=2&mode=DAY&showTitle=0&" +         replaceStr + "&ctz=Australia%2FVictoria&dates=" + startDate + "/" + startDate;
   } else if (role == "parent") {
  url = "https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showTabs=1&showCalendars=1&height=600&wkst=2&mode=MONTH&showTitle=0&"    + replaceStr + "&ctz=Australia%2FVictoria&dates=" + startDate + "/" + startDate;
     } else if (role == "teacher") {
  url = "https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showBorderTitle=1&showTabs=1&showCalendars=1&height=600&wkst=2&mode=WE   EK&showTitle=0&" + replaceStr + "&ctz=Australia%2FVictoria&dates=" + startDate +  "/" + startDate;
    } else {
 url = "https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showBorderTitle=1&showTabs=1&showCalendars=1&height=600&wkst=2&mode=MO  NTH&showTitle=0&" + replaceStr + "&ctz=Australia%2FVictoria&dates=" + startDate + "/" + startDate;
 }
```

Here is the code that gets all the users calendars:

```
var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
 var calendarIDs = [];
 for (var i=0;i<calendars.length;i++) {
  calendarIDs.push(calendars[i].getId()); 
 }
 Logger.log(calendarIDs);
 return calendarIDs;
}
```

Is there a way around this issue? I have tried google calendar permissions, editing the url parameters and fetching https://www.google.com/calendar/render#main_7 inside my app script using UrlFetchApp to load the page asynchronously without success. Any advise or if anyone has had the same issue as this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** I am able to show calendars that are owned by the user but the calendars which are shared to all domain users cannot be viewed unless the process above is executed. Are we not able to show calendars that are not public and not owned by the user, only shared?

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question anywhere in your post?

Comment: Sorry I will clarity asap

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with two calendars which are not allowed to be embedded. These were the contacts calendar and the holidays calendar. Once I had taken these out of the replaceStr string I was able to successfully load ALL of my calendars (up to 16) within a GAS iframe.

Corrected Code:

```
var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
          var calendarIDs = [];
          var notCalendarIDs = [];   
          for (var i=0;i<calendars.length;i++) {
              Logger.log("All calendars " + calendars[i].getId());

              if (calendars[i].getId() != "en.australian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com" && calendars[i].getId() != "#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com") {
                 calendarIDs.push(calendars[i].getId());
              } 
         }
```